# How do I bind to value from parent list?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a property exposed through my ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Tag> AllTags { get; set; }
```

where a `Tag` is

```
class Tag {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<int, int> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I then use this as an `ItemsSource` for a `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagListTemplate}" ItemsSource="
{Binding AllTags}">
</ListView>
```

Within my `TagListTemplate`
I then bind the second list to an `ItemsControl`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TagListTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TagName}"/>
        <ItemsControl  Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Currently the output looks like this:

```
Name [value, value]
     [value, value]
     [value, value]
Name2 [value,value]
      [value,value]
      [value,value]
```

and I would like the output to look like this:

```
Name [value, value]
Name [value, value]
Name [value, value]
Name2 [value,value]
Name2 [value,value]
Name2 [value,value]
```

How can I move the `Textblock` into the `ItemsControl` and have the name repeat for every element?
I have tried using `AncestorType` but could not get that to work correctly.

Comment: I modified my question a little, I tried to make it abstract, but I think it didn't help.  Let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: can you post your listview code with everything in between?

Comment: Updated again to include the full template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllTags}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tag}">

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ValuePair}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value2}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Notice this binding:

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}
```

When working with relative bindings, you need to explicitly specify the DataContext before the property!

Note: I could not compile your code with the double int values so I created a dummy type ValuePair for this. I assume this was not your exact code so it shouldn't matter.